# When I type inside an input value I want that input value to apear inside the span tag as textcontent as I type

Tags: javascript, dom

How do I see an input value inside an span tag when I am typing?

```js
let input = document.querySelector("input");
input.addEventListener("keypress", function(e) {
  let span = document.querySelector("span");
  span.textContent = input.value
})
```

```html
<span></span>
<input type="text">
```

Comment: Your code works....

Answer (score 0):

Use the event `keydown` instead of `keypress` so it can react to a `backspace` press. Also add a `setTimeout` to display the last key pressed.

```js
let input = document.querySelector("input");
input.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
  let span = document.querySelector("span");
  setTimeout(() => span.textContent = input.value);
})
```

```html
<span></span>
<input type="text">
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the event keydown to make it respond to backspace press.